# How to get attribute value from Xml using C

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing

I have the XML file as given as below

```
 -<fmiModelDescription numberOfEventIndicators="0" variableNamingConvention="structured" generationDateAndTime="2015-06-22T14:46:19Z" generationTool="Dassault Systemes FMU Export from Simulink, ver. 2.1.1 (MATLAB 8.7 (R2014b) 08-Sep-2014)" version="1.4" author="Dan Henriksson" description="S-function with FMI generated from Simulink model BouncingBalls" guid="{76da271a-0d11-469c-bc24-0343629fb38e}" modelName="BouncingBalls_sf" fmiVersion="2.0"> <CoSimulation canHandleVariableCommunicationStepSize="true" modelIdentifier="BouncingBalls_sf"/> <DefaultExperiment stepSize="0.001" stopTime="10.0" startTime="0.0"/> -<ModelVariables>
```

I want to fetch the attribute value for eg GUID which is given in the above XML,how can i do that using C programming

Comment: Use [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)

Comment: If you don't care that it's XML and it's just this very specific file format, you can use sscanf. But it's probably not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the only valid answer is: **use a library**!

The probably best one (in terms of feature completeness) is [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/). Use this if there aren't any other concerns. There's good documentation, too.

If you need something small, there are a LOT of options, all with their limitations. I recently created [badxml](https://github.com/Zirias/badxml/) for this purpose. There are many other options, such as [ezxml](http://ezxml.sourceforge.net/) which I discovered just today in a question here.

But as I said, if size is not a concern, just use **libxml**, because it is widely used, well tested and feature-complete.

Comment: other than using library is there any other way, just wanted to know.?

Comment: if you want an example on how to parse XML, look at [my implementation in badxml](https://github.com/Zirias/badxml/blob/master/src/badxml/badxml.c) -- note that this is absolutely **minimal** and doesn't support a lot of XML features. Parsing XML is a complex task and the general problem already has quite a few solutions, so going for doing it yourself is 1.) a **lot** of work, 2.) needs a good justification for the effort and 3.) is very easy to get wrong.